# Item spacing in a CollectionView when set to HorizontalList

Tags: maui

How do we set the spacing between items in a `CollectionView` in a .NET MAUI app when we set `ItemsLayout` to `HorizontalList`.

I actually use a `Border` around each item so I thought I could achieve it by setting the `Border` margin to `Margin="0,0,5,0"` but that didn't work.

Here's my code for `CollectionView`:

```
<CollectionView
   ItemsSource="{Binding MyOptions}"
   ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
   HeightRequest="30"
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate
         x:DataType="itemoption:MyModel">
       <Border
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray}"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 3"
            Padding="10">
            <Label
               Text="{Binding Name}"
               TextColor="{StaticResource Black}"
               FontSize="11"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

This is what it looks like now and I just want more separation between items.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ItemSpacing` property for that:

```xml
<CollectionView
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyOptions}"
    ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
    ItemSpacing="20">
    <!-- ... -->
</CollectionView>
```

You can find more info on [ItemSpacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout#item-spacing) in the official documentation.

Comment: IntelliSense is not giving me `ItemSpacing` under `CollectionView`

Comment: I needed to add `<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>` then `<LinearItemsLayout>`. It's all in the documentation you referenced. Thank you!